# how to ar x filename.a to different directory

Tags: linux, unix-ar

Is there any ar option to extract objects to a different directory ?
Any way to extract them to tmp below ?

```
[test]# ls -l
total 1828
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1859628 Aug 24 02:10 libclsr11.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Aug 24 02:12 tmp
[test]# ar x libclsr11.a
[test]# ls -l
total 3760
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  157304 Aug 24 02:13 clsrcact.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19304 Aug 24 02:13 clsrcclu.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55696 Aug 24 02:13 clsrccss.o
..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Aug 24 02:12 tmp
[test]#
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution depends on the version of `ar`. You can use `ar --version` to display the version of `ar` on your system.

**For ar / GNU binutils before version 2.34:**

Unfortunately, ar before version 2.34 does not provide a way to specify the directory where the files shall be extracted. (At least I was unable to find one.) It always uses the current directory. However, there is a simple workaround: Change to the target directory *before extraction* and use the relative path to the archive instead:

```
# cd ./tmp/
# ar x ../libclsr11.a
```

This way you should end up with clsrcact.o, clsrcclu.o and clsrccss.o inside the ./tmp/ directory.

**For ar / GNU binutils version 2.34 or later:**

Version 2.34 of binutils introduced the `--output` for the `ar` program. (See [the changelog](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=binutils/NEWS;hb=refs/tags/binutils-2_34).) It can be used to specify the directory where the contents shall be extracted:

```
# ar x --output tmp libclsr11.a
```

That way the archive contents will land inside the `tmp` directory without having to use the workaround for earlier `ar` versions.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is possible, maybe was changed recently, `--output` option is what you need.

In your example:

```
ar x libclsr11.a --output tmp
```

Comment: Yes. The `--output` option was introduced in version 2.34 of ar / binutils which was released in February 2020, more than three years after the initial answer. I've updated my answer to include the new option for more recent versions.